# Python Graduated Symbols

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, indentationerror

I am currently struggling with creating graduated symbols via Python. Based on ArcGISHelp 10.1 - GraduatedSymbolsSymbology (arcpy.mapping) I am doing as follows:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
   if lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_SYMBOLS":
     lyr.symbology.valueField = "POP2007"
     lyr.symbology.numClasses = 5
del mxd
```

Naturally, I am adjusting the mxd file, the value field, and the number of classes. I do, however, get this error:

Parsing error IndentationError: expected an indented block (line 3)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, white space is significant in Python. After a for or if, you need to indent (usually by two spaces, though some prefer tabs). I am not sure where your del mxd belongs in the above, but I have attempted to edit your code to at least be valid Python.

Answer (score 2):

Your error says it all.  It is poor formatting.  Python relies on indentations.  Format it like:

```
import arcpy mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd") 
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd): 
  if lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_SYMBOLS":
    lyr.symbology.valueField = "POP2007"   
    lyr.symbology.numClasses = 5 
del mxd
```

**Edit:**  Just to be clear, I am only addressing the `IndentationError` as I am not familiar with using arcpy and symbology types.  I am only addressing the syntax, not the content.